# How do you run a patch/partial database UPDATE in Scala Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

We'd like to run a patch/partial `UPDATE` with Slick (3.0.0) so that we only modify some of the fields in a record. Exactly which fields will be updated exactly will only be known at runtime.

For example, for a [REST `PATCH` request](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/patch/).

Currently we run a `SELECT` first to get the original record then run an `UPDATE` but it would be nicer to do this in a single SQL statement.

Something like this:

```
def patchPerson(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int]) = {
   people.filter(_.name === "M Odersky")
       .map(p => 
           (name, age) match {
              case (Some(_), Some(_)) => (p.name, p.age)
              case (Some(_), None)    => (p.name)
              case (None   , Some(_)) => (p.age)
           }
       )
       .update(
           (name, age) match {
              case (Some(_), Some(_)) => (name.get, age.get)
              case (Some(_), None)    => (name.get)
              case (None   , Some(_)) => (age.get)
           }
       )
}
```

*(Please ignore the ugly code here)*

The above does not compile with the following error message:

> No matching Shape found. Slick does not know how to map the given
>   types. Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your *
>   projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala
>   List).   Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel      Source type:
>   Object    Unpacked type: T      Packed type: G

And:

> not enough arguments for method map: (implicit shape:
>   slick.lifted.Shape[_ <: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel, Object, T,
>   G])slick.lifted.Query[G,T,Seq]. Unspecified value parameter shape.

I assume this is because Slick expects the tuple length and type to match the results for both the `filter` and `update` functions.

We've tried using the Slick [heterogeneous list](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#slick.collection.heterogeneous.HList) class but this also seems to expect the length and types to match.

Is there a way to write this in Slick so that we can update an arbitrary number of fields in a record with one database call?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: What about just running native SQL?

Comment: I've added a bounty since I have the exact same problem as the author. @LukasEder that wouldn't work well if you don't know which keys you're patching. E.g. I have a large User case class to update, and I'd like to have a generic PATCH endpoint to which I can simply send one updated field.

Comment: I found an answer to a similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42004236/7505973

Answer (score 5):

Why not do the pattern matching before constructing the update query?

```
def patchPerson(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int]) = {
   val query = people.filter(_.name === "M Odersky")
   (name, age) match {
     case (Some(name), Some(age)) =>
       query.map(p => (p.name, p.age)).update(name, age)
     case (Some(name), None) =>
       query.map(p => p.name).update(name)
     case (None, Some(age)) =>
       query.map(p => p.age).update(age)
   }
}
```

Comment: nice, tks. it was useful

Comment: unfortunately, this is not really scalable, for `n` `Option`s you get `2^n` cases

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be to run a [plain SQL query](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html)

Even if the SQL query has 2 parts, the relational database management system (postgresql, mysql, etc) is able to tune the query under the hoods.

I'm not sure if in this case Slick is able to optimize, but in several cases it also [optimizes the queries](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql-to-slick.html#non-optimal-sql-code) by itself.

Typical update:

```
def updateRecord(id: Long, field1: Int) = {
    db.withSession {
      self.filter(_.id === id).map(_.field1).update(field1)
    }
}
```

Doing your type of update would require a bit more logic like you did. Don't think it's possible to simplify if you only know at runtime which fields to change. But you can force the update, using existing value for the field on the record as a fallback (may lead to more updates on DB than it should)

```
def updateRecord(id: Long, field1: Option[Int], field2: Option[Int]) = {
    db.withSession {
        self.filter(_.id === id).map(_.field1, _.field2).update(field1.getOrElse(existingValue1), field2.getOrElse(existingValue2)) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I also believe plain SQL is currently the right solution for this problem. Slick probably  could optimize one update per field to one SQL update as you propose as alternative. The only real problem is how to obtain existingValueX without an extra query. The whole idea of this question is to avoid SELECT + UPDATE. Really a pity that the update function does not receive the current values.

Answer (score 0):

You already have answers as written by @pedrorijo91 and @thirstycow but i'll try to explain why this doesnt work.

I'm havent used slick 3 but im guessing its because the map function doesnt return a consistent type for it to run update against.  As a thought experiment, if you cut your call at map what do you think the type will be?

```
val partialQuery:??? = people.filter(_.name === "M Odersky")
       .map(p => 
           (name, age) match {
              case (Some(_), Some(_)) => (p.name, p.age)
              case (Some(_), None)    => (p.name)
              case (None   , Some(_)) => (p.age)
           }
       );

val fullQuery:??? = partialQuery.update {
       (name, age) match {
          case (Some(_), Some(_)) => (name.get, age.get)
          case (Some(_), None)    => (name.get)
          case (None   , Some(_)) => (age.get)
       }    
}
```

The matcher returns different "shapes" at compile time which im guessing will revert to Any type.

Comment: I just want to add, there is actually a 3rd solution, which is to write a macro.  Im not going to go into the details here, but it will not look like your solution at all (but maybe cooler?)