# Slick 3.0.0 - update row with only non-null values

Tags: scala, functional-programming, slick, slick-3.0

Having a table with the columns

```
class Data(tag: Tag) extends Table[DataRow](tag, "data") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def state = column[State]("state")
  def price = column[Int]("price")

  def * = (id.?, name, state, price) <> ((DataRow.apply _).tupled, DataRow.unapply)
}
```

I'd like to write a function that would select a single row, and update the columns where the supplied values are not null.

```
def update(id: Int, name: Option[String], state: Option[State], price: Option[Int])
```

eg.

`update(1, None, None, Some(5))` would update only the price of the data row 1, leaving the name and state intact

`update(1, Some("foo"), None, Some(6))` would update the name and price, but leave its state intact.

I guess some smart mapping could be used, but I'm having a hard time expressing it, not sure how it could spit out different length tuples depending on the inputs (wether their value is defined), since they are more or less "unrelated" classes.

```
def update(id: Int, name: Option[String], state: Option[State], price: Option[Int]) = {
  table.fiter(_.id == id). ???? .update(name, state, price)
}
```

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848004/how-do-you-run-a-patch-partial-database-update-in-scala-slick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [JonasAnso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649319/slick-3-0-0-update-row-with-only-non-null-values/35795527#35795527), converting that to slick v3.0+, and putting it into a transaction:

```
  def partialUpdate(id: Int, name: Option[String], login: Option[String]): Future[Int] = {
    val selectQ = users.filter(_.id === id)

    val query = selectQ.result.head.flatMap { data =>
      selectQ.update(data.patch(name, login))
    }

    db.run(query)
  }
```

Comment: Nice work. I have tested it and of course still 2 SQL statements are executed, one for the SELECT and one for the update. But I like a lot that there is only one db.run

Comment: Yeah, still two statements, but now they are wrapped in a single transaction, so it should be as safe against race conditions as the DB manager is.

Comment: it's only safe against race conditions if you do a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` query, wrapping in a transaction by itself does not help at all (but it appears `forUpdate` support was only added to Slick after this answer was posted https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1454)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it in the following way.

The implementation below works only if it is a Product object.

Execute the update statement except for None for the Option type and null for the object type.

```
package slick.extensions

import slick.ast._
import slick.dbio.{ Effect, NoStream }
import slick.driver.JdbcDriver
import slick.jdbc._
import slick.lifted._
import slick.relational.{ CompiledMapping, ProductResultConverter, ResultConverter, TypeMappingResultConverter }
import slick.util.{ ProductWrapper, SQLBuilder }

import scala.language.{ existentials, higherKinds, implicitConversions }

trait PatchActionExtensionMethodsSupport { driver: JdbcDriver =>

  trait PatchActionImplicits {
    implicit def queryPatchActionExtensionMethods[U <: Product, C[_]](
        q: Query[_, U, C]
    ): PatchActionExtensionMethodsImpl[U] =
      createPatchActionExtensionMethods(updateCompiler.run(q.toNode).tree, ())
  }

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Patch Actions
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  type PatchActionExtensionMethods[T <: Product] = PatchActionExtensionMethodsImpl[T]

  def createPatchActionExtensionMethods[T <: Product](tree: Node, param: Any): PatchActionExtensionMethods[T] =
    new PatchActionExtensionMethodsImpl[T](tree, param)

  class PatchActionExtensionMethodsImpl[T <: Product](tree: Node, param: Any) {
    protected[this] val ResultSetMapping(_, CompiledStatement(_, sres: SQLBuilder.Result, _),
      CompiledMapping(_converter, _)) = tree
    protected[this] val converter = _converter.asInstanceOf[ResultConverter[JdbcResultConverterDomain, Product]]
    protected[this] val TypeMappingResultConverter(childConverter, toBase, toMapped) = converter
    protected[this] val ProductResultConverter(elementConverters @ _ *) =
      childConverter.asInstanceOf[ResultConverter[JdbcResultConverterDomain, Product]]
    private[this] val updateQuerySplitRegExp = """(.*)(?<=set )((?:(?= where)|.)+)(.*)?""".r
    private[this] val updateQuerySetterRegExp = """[^\s]+\s*=\s*\?""".r

    /** An Action that updates the data selected by this query. */
    def patch(value: T): DriverAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write] = {
      val (seq, converters) = value.productIterator.zipWithIndex.toIndexedSeq
        .zip(elementConverters)
        .filter {
          case ((Some(_), _), _) => true
          case ((None, _), _) => false
          case ((null, _), _) => false
          case ((_, _), _) => true
        }
        .unzip

      val (products, indexes) = seq.unzip

      val newConverters = converters.zipWithIndex
        .map(c => (c._1, c._2 + 1))
        .map {
          case (c: BaseResultConverter[_], idx) => new BaseResultConverter(c.ti, c.name, idx)
          case (c: OptionResultConverter[_], idx) => new OptionResultConverter(c.ti, idx)
          case (c: DefaultingResultConverter[_], idx) => new DefaultingResultConverter(c.ti, c.default, idx)
          case (c: IsDefinedResultConverter[_], idx) => new IsDefinedResultConverter(c.ti, idx)
        }

      val productResultConverter =
        ProductResultConverter(newConverters: _*).asInstanceOf[ResultConverter[JdbcResultConverterDomain, Any]]
      val newConverter = TypeMappingResultConverter(productResultConverter, (p: Product) => p, (a: Any) => toMapped(a))

      val newValue: Product = new ProductWrapper(products)
      val newSql = sres.sql match {
        case updateQuerySplitRegExp(prefix, setter, suffix) =>
          val buffer = StringBuilder.newBuilder
          buffer.append(prefix)
          buffer.append(
            updateQuerySetterRegExp
              .findAllIn(setter)
              .zipWithIndex
              .filter(s => indexes.contains(s._2))
              .map(_._1)
              .mkString(", ")
          )
          buffer.append(suffix)
          buffer.toString()
      }

      new SimpleJdbcDriverAction[Int]("patch", Vector(newSql)) {
        def run(ctx: Backend#Context, sql: Vector[String]): Int =
          ctx.session.withPreparedStatement(sql.head) { st =>
            st.clearParameters
            newConverter.set(newValue, st)
            sres.setter(st, newConverter.width + 1, param)
            st.executeUpdate
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example

```
// Model
case class User(
  id: Option[Int] = None,
  name: Option[String] = None,
  username: Option[String] = None,
  password: Option[String] = None
)

// Table
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def username = column[String]("username")
  def password = column[String]("password")
  override def * = (id.?, name.?, username.?, password.?) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

// TableQuery
object Users extends TableQuery(new Users(_))

// CustomDriver 
trait CustomDriver extends PostgresDriver with PatchActionExtensionMethodsSupport {
  override val api: API = new API {}
  trait API extends super.API  with PatchActionImplicits
}

// Insert
Users += User(Some(1), Some("Test"), Some("test"), Some("1234"))

// User patch
Users.filter(_.id === 1).patch(User(name = Some("Change Name"), username = Some("")))
```

https://gist.github.com/bad79s/1edf9ea83ba08c46add03815059acfca

Answer (score 1):

As I commented the question is similar to an existing one, but you don't seem to have any extra requirements.

The simplest approach is just SELECT + UPDATE. For example you add a patch function in your DataRow class defining how you want to update your model

```
      def patch(name: Option[String], state: Option[State], price: Option[Int]): Data {
         this.copy(name = name.getOrElse(this.name), ...)
      }
```

And you add a partialUpdate method in your repo class

```
class DataRepo {
  private val Datas = TableQuery[Data]
  val db = ???

  def partialUpdate(id: Int, name: Option[String], state: Option[State], price: Option[Int]): Future[Int] = {
    val query = Datas.filter(_.id === id)
    for {
      data <- db.run(query.result.head)
      result <- db.run(query.update(data.patch(name, state, price)))
    } yield result
  }

}
```

As you see the main problem of this solution is that there are 2 SQL statements, SELECT and UPDATE.

Other solution is to use plain SQL (http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html) but of course this gives other problems.

Comment: Thanks, see my answer above for a little bit of improvement.

Comment: Hi @jonas-anso  !  I actually needed to do this today... I am happy to find your answer, even if it is not the one I was hoping for (two queries or else raw SQL? lame...)

Comment: Found a blog post here outlining more like what we want to achieve https://www.missingfaktor.me/writing/2018/08/12/composable-table-updates-in-slick/ but unfortunately it seems to be kind of complicated and you have to define your own slick extension 